# Get pagination to work on my custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination, custom-post-type

Hey I have been trying to get pagination working on my custom post type - I have had some sort of success with this code here (below) however when I turn permalinks back onto the %postname% setting I get a 404 when I a click next page but on the default permalinks in works fine.

I have tried the solutions here but to no avail - http://wordpress.org/support/topic/pagination-with-custom-post-type-getting-a-404?replies=1#post-1616810

If anyone can help that would be brilliant.

```
<?php
$type = 'faqs';
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args=array(
  'post_type' => $type,
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'paged' => $paged,
  'posts_per_page' => 1,
  'caller_get_posts'=> 1
);
$temp = $wp_query;  // assign original query to temp variable for later use
$wp_query = null;
$wp_query = new WP_Query();
$wp_query->query($args);
?>

   <?php if($wp_query->have_posts()) : while($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>

<div class="faq-container">
<div class="faq-question">
<h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
</div>

<div class="faq-answer">
<p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read full answer &rarr;</a>
</div>
</div>

<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: `caller_get_posts` is a long depreciated argument. It has been replaced with `ignore_sticky_posts`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once I also faced this type of problem becouse I have a custom post type's name and page's slug the same.

In my case I had the custom post type "book" and then a page called "book" with the slug "book" to display the custom post type's posts.

However this causes conflict with WordPress's rewrite rules and as a result was triggering my 404 error.

The solution was simply to change the "book" page's slug to "books" or anything other than "book" actually.

may this help you....

Comment: I'll give this a try now :)

Comment: It works a treat - thank you! I would of been here for hour if you hadn't of answered. Thanks :)

Comment: I would upvote but I don't have enough rep - apologies